# Azure Function App Dependency Inject Logger not logging

Tags: azure, logging, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I have a Function App that I’m trying to use DI in a class for the logger so that I don’t have to pass the ILogger to every function. I’ve been doing some research and found where I’m supposed to use `ILogger` in the class constructor. I’ve done all of the changes I believe are correct but it’s still not logging anything from that class.

I’ve added the logging to my Startup class, updated the hosts.json file, and used ILogger in the constructor. There are no errors but nothing gets logged. Does anyone see something I’m missing?

Startup.cs

```cs
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.AddLogging();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IDataManager, DataManager>();
}
```

Host.json

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Debug"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

DataManager.cs

```cs
public class DataManager : IDataManager
{
    private DataContext _db;
    private readonly ILogger<DataManager> _log;

    public DataManager(ILogger<DataManager> log, DataContext dataContext)
    {
        _db = dataContext;
        _log = log;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced it in my environment and got the expected results as below and the code taken from @nareshnagpal06 's [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/nareshnagpal06/82c6b4df2a987087425c32adb58312c2) repository:

**Startup.cs:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection; // install nuget - "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions"
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp50.Startup))]

namespace FunctionApp50
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHelperClass, HelperClass>();

        }
    }
}
```

**HelperClass.cs:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace FunctionApp50
{
    public class HelperClass : IHelperClass
    {
        private static ILogger<IHelperClass> _logger;
        public HelperClass(ILogger<IHelperClass> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        public void Dowork()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Dowork: Execution Started");
            /* rest of the functionality below
                .....
                .....
            */
            _logger.LogInformation("Dowork: Execution Completed");
        }
    }
}
```

**IHelperClass.cs:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace FunctionApp50
{
    public interface IHelperClass
    {
        void Dowork();
    }
}
```

**Function1.cs:**

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp50
{
    public class Function1 // Ensure class is not static (which comes by default)
    {
        private IHelperClass _helper;

        public Function1(IHelperClass helper)
        {
            _helper = helper;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            // call helper 
            _helper.Dowork();
        }
    }
}
```

**host.json:**

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "Function": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

**Terminal Output:**

[image]

**File Output:**

Firstly go to run, then paste `%temp%\LogFiles\Application\Functions.`,then click on Host file in the location then click on log file then the output is:

[image]

Comment: I'm still not showing in App Insights. I have everything you have, with the exception that I'm calling mine DataManger instead of HelperClass. The "ILogger log" in my Function is logging but once I go to my DataManager class nothing gets logged. Only thing I really saw to change was that I was using  private static ILogger<DataManager> _log  and changed it to use the Interface like you have.  private static ILogger<IDataManager> _log. I also specifically added "Namespace.DataManager": "Debug" versus just "Namespace":"Debug" in hosts file. I see logs in terminal but not App Insights.

Comment: I didn't understand where to look for the File Output. Are looking at that on your local machine or in the Azure Portal? I'm running in Azure and looking at Azure App Insights.

Comment: In **Logs** section of Application Insights I got logs as https://i.imgur.com/t4jWcHD.png  You can check using query **Traces**

Comment: You will get logs as i have got