# How can we assign a particular path for log files in Azure functionapp in visual studio

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-functions, logfile

I have got the path of log file stored in my machine but i need the location to be changed how can it be possible to change the path

I have tried getting the log files..1st and now I want to change the path location of log file

Answer (score 0):

In the host.json file, add the following code to specify the path for log files:

```
 {
  "logger": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Firstly go to run, then paste `%temp%\LogFiles\Application\Functions.` , then click on Host file in the location then click on log file then you will get output:
[image]

**References taken from**:

- [Azure Function App Dependency Inject Logger not logging - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75441463/azure-function-app-dependency-inject-logger-not-logging/75443526#75443526)